# Which IDE should I use for Vala?

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, application-development, ide, vala

I think the title explains it already...

Answer (score 14):

As @aperson said, [Geany](http://geany.org/) is a very good text editor - It is lightweight with lots of features. It also supports vala (you need to install `valac` first though for full vala features). A lot of its features are IDE like eg. you can build/run with 1 click.

[image: geany vala]

To install, run `sudo apt-get install valac geany` or search for 'valac' and 'geany' in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: You apparently have the better answer.  I guess I need to be more informative to appease the community.

Comment: How in the world can one compile all the files in the project with Vala? I know there are build/compile options, but I haven't a clue how to get them linked so I can use one file in another.

Comment: Geany claims to be an IDE: "Geany - The Flyweight IDE", not just a text editor

Answer (score 9):

There is new project called Valama, you can check:

https://github.com/Valama/valama

It uses gtksourceview, so editor experience is similar to gedit, but it's still in early development phase.

**UPDATE**: It is getting better every day, there is active development on going.

Comment: As of April 2020 this project hasn't seen activity in master branch for 5 years.  It's dead.  I'd suggest trying GNOME Builder (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder) as mentioned below.

Answer (score 6):

There are two plugins for Gedit that provide Vala support.  Valencia and VTG both add autocompletion, symbol browsing and basic project management through makefiles

Valencia is the easier of the two to setup because VTG depends on gtksourcecompletion, but VTG has made several recent releases.

http://yorba.org/valencia/
http://code.google.com/p/vtg/

Comment: Someone unrelated but I think your Vala blog is about to disappear unfortunately. It's been useful for me and probably others as well so it's a shame to see it go.

Comment: The GNOME developers now have GNOME Builder (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder).  NOTE: GNOME also develops Gedit.

Answer (score 5):

Anjuta supports vala since ver. 2.31.3 and there's a nice plugin for gedit. http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/valencia/wiki

Answer (score 3):

I can't recommend an IDE specifically, but I can recommend [Geany](http://geany.org) as a great text editor.

Comment: Sorry I cant answer your question so here is an answer to a question I do know the answer to.

Comment: I don't see the need for IDEs because text editors like geany sort of negate any of my reasons for one.  I'm sorry you couldn't find my comment helpful; I feel my answer is still relevant to the question asked.

Comment: IDE's are merely over-glorified text editors.

Comment: +1 You can't be voted down for saying Geany when the top answer so far is .. Geany. Geany rocks and I would argue that with the terminal plugin, you can use ssh / scp / ftp / svn / bzr / diff / meld etc from the command line. It has all the features you get in a "real" IDE. BTW I don't program in Vala so perhaps I should get voted down too.

Comment: I don't care about the downvotes, what puzzles me is that my answer was the first.  In any case, I love geany and it's my editor of choice.  It has a great feature set and is immensely useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Val(a)IDE](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/24) seems to be the only IDE with Vala support, so if you want an IDE that is properly the way to go. Personally I use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) for my coding needs, I think it makes good sense to use a powerfull editor instead of a single purpose IDE.
Instead of knowing 20% of the commands (keyboard shortcuts) in five IDE's I can get to know 99% of the commands in one editor.

Comment: Except manually editing CMake/Make/Automake projects is a pain and that alone merits an IDE. I'm a big VIM fan, but if I need project management, I'd have to go with an IDE. And that's not even taking into account the convenience of auto complete, symbol tables, real-time syntax checking, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one has mentioned [Gnome Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder).

Upon opening the IDE, you can see the kinds of projects it supports (which also includes ones written in Vala):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Val(a)IDE](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/24), you can find the source/binary at [launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~tarnyko/valide)

The link to [Val(a)IDE](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/24) given by [SourceLab](https://askubuntu.com/a/3312/97755) seems to be broken.

References:

- [Vala (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29#IDE_support)
- [Official Vala Documentation](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Documentation#Vala_Specific)